# Из представления не возвращается модель

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть простая модель и метод Post контроллера. На входе у него данная модель, которая создается в представлении. Суть в том, что в контроллер она передается как NULL.
**Модель**

```
public class mLogin
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

**Контроллер**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult auth()
    {
        return View();
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult auth(mLogin login)
    {
        return View("View", login);
    }
```

**Представление** метода auth()

```
@model LE_mvc.Models.mLogin

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Login)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pass)
    <input type="submit" value="Войти" />
}
```

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что в методе `auth(mLogin login)` параметр называется `login` - точно так же, как и одно из свойств в модели (с точностью до регистра символов). Стандартный model binder в первую очередь пытается извлечь данные, сопоставив имена параметров метода и имена параметров в query string (или в теле запроса в данном случае). Поскольку имена параметров совпали, binder попытается привести значение, введенное в поле `Login`, к типу `mLogin`, что и приводит к ошибке.

Просто переименуйте параметр метода `auth`.

Comment: По поводу регистра я с Вами не соглашусь. Все же поле с заглавной, а объект со строчной. Но переименовав сам объект, все заработало. Не знаю как прокомментировать это. С ASP только знакомлюсь, но c C# уже давно и о таком даже не опдумал. В любом случае спасибо, впредь буду внимательнее